# Place a div top of page without position:fixed or JavaScript?

Tags: css, html, css-position

I need a `div` placed at the top and center of the page to appear over top of the scrolling content below it, and stay in place at the user scrolls.

However, due to freakishly annoying bug I can not reproduce in jsFiddle (or I'd ask for help with that instead) I can't use `position:fixed` and I need it to work without JavaScript.

How else can I do it?

Comment: try position:absolute; or float:em stacked, but without anything to look at, it's pretty much wide open.

Comment: What do you mean, nothing to look at?

Comment: He means you didnt supply any code...

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to?

Comment: What would this bug even be?  Are you using IE or something?

Comment: @Ezra: So we can see your progress and assist you based on that.

Comment: `position: fixed` is the correct way to do this. You should be trying to fix the bug, not finding an alternative to a simple solution.

Comment: No, it is a bug that appears in Firefox 7. Can we focus on the question at hand?

Comment: Oh very well then. Its just annoying to explain..

Comment: Sorry to annoy you with our silly request to see your code... so good luck getting things to behave as `position:fixed` without using `position:fixed`.  StackOverflow is also about helping future readers so this whole thing is pretty much useless in that regard too.

Comment: I only asked if there was another way to do it. Surely if answers were given (and they were) it would be helpful to everyone.

Comment: I took exception to your attitude towards people asking questions only in an effort to help.  And the only posted answer uses `position:fixed`, so how exactly does that answer the question of how to do this _without_ using `position:fixed`?

Comment: Yeah technically it dosent either. this is the bug finally explained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943585/fixed-positioning-bug-in-firefox-7-0-1-some-overflow-seems-to-cause-1px-margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean and I've made a little example, it's pretty self explanatory but just say if you don't understand anything, sure you will.

And if I've misunderstood, I apologise... [jsFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/T6YFz/)

**EDIT With Real Fix**

Since I read the question wrong and a fixed position couldn't be used, I have now altered the code slightly to the following [jsFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/JXWNj/)

Basically you're placing a transparent fixed div to fill the entire width of the page, and then placing your absolute position div inside that, creating the same effect but hopefully getting round the bug you've come across.

Comment: That uses `position: fixed`, which the question explicitly rules out.

Comment: More or less, bus I cant use 'position:fixed' in the CSS.

Comment: Could you not wrap the absolute positiond div in a fixed div like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HelloJoe/JXWNj/

Comment: Hmm good news, that works so you can answer the thread with that i suppose. Bad news I still have the same bug. :(

Comment: @HelloJoe, if you post that as the answer you get accepted! :D Your idea fixed everything!! :D including that annoying bug! <3 <3 <3

Comment: @Ezra, I have edited my original answer to the new fix, good luck with the rest of your site! :)

Comment: @HelloJoe, Technically your Edited solution is still wrong, height:100%; never works like it sounds. But Its given me a better idea for a solution than the one I got from your last answer. :P You are an inspiration xD

Comment: `height: 100%` works only when every parent element of it has a height set. So if you have the structure: `html > body > div > div > div` all of them, right back to the html properties, needs a define height for the browser to determine the height of the very last div for example. You also need to take into account margins/paddings of each element to! But either way, I'm glad something I've said has helped :)